# Twitter Data-Analyse: What can I do with the data?

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning, data-science-model, topic-model, twitter

I retrieve data to a specific topic from Twitter and did my sentiment analysis on it. I never did anything in NLP, etc. So what else can I do with that? "Main goal" would be to find out if the Twitter community is against this "topic" or not.

I am also struggling with cleaning the data and I mean by that, that I am unsure how much should I clean on that Tweet.

I would be also glad to get any advise on books, articles, communities, videos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community analysis implies [graph analysis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure)

here is a short list of things you can work on:

1. People often reshares tweets among a certain social group. Minimum-cut method, Girvan–Newman and Modularity maximization are someof the starting algorithms to extract these type of substructures.
2. You can try and find different hierarchies among the groups sharing a particular topics
3. You can try and analyse the lifetime of tweets for particular topics (survival analysis)

Analysing tweets is closer to graph analytics rather than NLP.
Here is a great overview on [community analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0612.pdf). For coding and algorithms, please [check graphX Spark library](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html). If your data is not too large, [networkX is easier](https://networkx.org/).
For survival analysis, [lifeline](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is one of the easier options.